# Почему пропал screen?

Tags: java, linux, gnu-screen

У меня debian 9, через screen запускается java приложение "server".

Так же есть другое java приложение "reloader", которое проверяет работу первого. При необходимости reloader запускает server, если тот упал.

Проверка работоспособности осуществляется за счет проверки наличия скрина следующим скриптом:

```
#!/bin/bash

SCRNAME="skyblock2"

screen -wipe $SCRNAME > /dev/null 2>&1

SCR=`screen -ls | grep "^\s" | grep "\.\$SCRNAME\s"`;

if [ "$SCR" != "" ];
then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

И все это работает, но иногда случается такое, что screen сервера куда-то пропадает, хотя само java приложение работает. Сегодня случилось такое:

```
[05:10:43 INFO]: [skyblock2] [+] Сервер успешно обновился и работает.
[05:20:37 INFO]: [skyblock2] Нет screen сервера, включаем сервер...
[05:20:37 INFO]: Отправляем письмо skyblock2 - СЕРВЕР ВЫКЛЮЧИЛСЯ, ВКЛЮЧАЕМ
```

Важное уточнение:
screen попал не момент перезапуска, а после перезапуска спустя 10 минут аптайма java приложения server. пропал именно сокет screen из `screen -ls`

В чем может быть дело?

Comment: *сервер был перезапущен* — т.е., был запущен **новый** процесс, а «старый» завершил работу. ну а следом завершил работу и процесс screen, который мультиплексировал потоки ввода-вывода для «старого» процесса. всё штатно, именно так мультиплексор и должен действовать.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вы не поняли. перезагрузка была в 05:10, а в 05:20 screen пропал. скрин существовал 10 минут после перезагрузи сервера, а потом пропал. а процесс java остался и работает до сих пор, я его пока не отключаю. сервер запускается всегда через screen -dmS java ... и так далее

Comment: я основываюсь на ваших словах. если под «сервер был перезапущен» вы подразумеваете не запуск **нового** процесса (с одновременным или отложенным на время прекращением работы старого процесса), то стоит внести уточнения в текст вопроса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin про перезапуск я написал лишь потому, что проблема происходит после перезапуска сервера спустя 10 минут. смотрите, перезапуск: сервер выключается и скрин соответственно удаляется, потом запускается новый процесс java с новым скрином. первая минута, java процесс есть, screen есть; 5 минута, java процесс есть, screen есть; 10 минута, java процесс есть, скрин пропал; 1 час uptime, java процесс есть, скрина нет. не знаю, как еще понятнее объяснить. факт есть факт, у меня прямо СЕЙЧАС работает java процесс, а его screen куда-то пропал, его нет, а java процесс (рабочий) есть еще

Comment: новый процесс java запускается только после полной остановки предыдущего процесса

Comment: 1. стоит внести уточнение в текст вопроса. 2. вы, видимо, путаете процесс и сокет. процесс screen наверняка никуда не делся, и присутствует в списке процессов. а сокет, созданный этим процессом, вполне может быть и удалён (например, командой `screen -wipe`). именно про сокеты «рассказывает» вам команда `screen -ls`. не про процессы, а про сокеты. // да, сокет автоматически удаляется при завершении процесса, его создавшего, но удаление сокета не приводит к завершению процесса, его создавшего.

Comment: я бы порекомендовал попробовать убрать вызов команды `screen -wipe` и понаблюдать за происходящим.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin поправил вопрос. спасибо за пояснение с сокетами, это внесло ясность. проблема редко проявляется, когда удасться проверить, отпишу в ответ

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin убрал -wipe, но не помогло. проблема проявилась сегодня. как я и говорил, редко случается. сейчас сервер работает, а сокета его скрина нет, хоть  и запускался сервер командой `screen -dmS $SCRNAME bash -c "...."`

Comment: ну, значит, тот процесс, который вы называете «сервером», запустил дочерний процесс без привязки к контрольному терминалу родительского. вот дочерний процесс и работает. а родительский завершился, а следом за ним завершился и процесс программы screen, к контрольному терминалу которого  был привязан родительский: у него ведь не осталось более ни одного контролируемого им процесса.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin что странно, у меня в tmux консоль сервера осталась открытой через `screen -r`. и если я ее скрою через `ctrl + A и D`, то уже открыть обратно не выйдет, т.к. сокета скрина уже нет

Comment: ничего не понял по поводу программы tmux и её отношения к программе screen, но это неважно: разбирайтесь с действиями той программой, которую вы называете «сервер», а не с якобы неправильной работой программой screen.

Comment: открытый screen остался в сессии tmux'a, но сокета скрина нет. я не знаю, что тут разбираться. сервер работает, его консоль открыта, команды писать можно. если консоль закрыть, уже обратно открыть не выйдет, т.к. в screen -ls нет сокета. ладно пофиг... я понял, что в данной ситуации вы не можете помочь, потому что инфы мало, я сам не понимаю

Comment: откуда взялась программа tmux и зачем вы используете одновременно **две разных** [программы-мультиплексора терминала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Терминальный_мультиплексор): tmux и gnu/screen?

Comment: tmux я использую, как рабочий стол, чтобы переключаться между разными окнами, не более. он никак не связан с screen. просто у меня в одном из окне tmux'a был открыт screen через `screen -r`. и когда сокет screen'a сервера пропал, он по прежнему остался открытым в одном окне tmux. я по этому и говорю, скрин как бы есть и его как бы нет. он у меня открыт остался через `screen -r`, но сокета уже нет

Comment: ну, попробуйте избавиться от одного из двух мультиплексоров: используйте либо tmux, либо gnu/screen.